# C to C# (Mono) memory mapped files/shared memory in linux

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono, shared-memory

I'm working on an embedded system that aquires about 20 megs of data per second. My lower-level acquisition, control, and processing layer converts most of it into a handful of important values, but it can also be useful for the end user to get a view of a window of the unprocessed data.

I'm working on an ASP.NET front end in C# with mod-mono. I would like the server-side part of the ASP.NET page to be able to easily request the last half-second or so worth of data. The C++ code has real-time constraints, so I can't use message passing to respond - it could easily get bogged down by too many clients or someone quickly refreshing. I would like it to be able to place the data somewhere where any number of C# readers can access it as needed.

I'm picturing an area of shared memory with a rolling buffer of the least 16 or 32MB of data. The C++ code is constantly updating it, and the C# code can peek at it whenever it wants to. Is there a way to handle this? All the information I find on using memory-mapped files seems to focus on forking a child, rather than having two unrelated processes use it for IPC - does it have to hit the disk (or fs cache, etc) before the C# application can see it, or does memory mapping from the two programs actually make them share the same pages?

Is there a way of accessing POSIX shared memory objects in C#?

Comment: Memory mapping seems to be right direction to *pass data*. As I understand it, for IPC communications you still need something to tell "ok, get updated view now" (to call [CreateView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267538.aspx)), which can be a named mutex or a simple polling. There are also [pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr I'll just be doing simple polling - I know that as long as the system is on, data is being read for me to peek at. I'm more concerned about whether or not memory mapped files will work properly between Mono and C. I'm afraid it will look like it's working, but will actually rely on the filesystem/disk instead of both processes mapping the same page in memory.

Comment: It's in POSIX description, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap).

Answer (score 9):

Here, an example with C program and C# program sharing information (two different processes) by means of a memory-mapped file:

1. From console create file: dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/sharedfile bs=12288 count=1
2. The C# program:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
   using System.Threading;

   namespace FileSharedMemory
   {
       class MainClass
       {
           public static void Main (string[] args)
           {

               using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("/tmp/sharedfile", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, "/tmp/sharedfile"))
               {
                   using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream ()) {
                       // 1. C program, filled memory-mapped file with the 'G' character (200 characters)
                       var data = stream.ReadByte ();
                       while (data != -1)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine ((char)data);
                           data = stream.ReadByte ();
                        }

                        // 2. We write "Goose" at the beginning of memory-mapped file.
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        var buffer = new byte[] { 0x47, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x73, 0x65 };
                        stream.Write (buffer, 0, 5);

                        Thread.Sleep (20000);

                        // 3. C program, filled memory-mapped file with the 'H' character (200 characters)
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        data = stream.ReadByte ();
                        while (data != -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine ((char)data);
                            data = stream.ReadByte ();
                        }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. The C program:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/mman.h>
   #include <errno.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int fd;
       int index;
       char *data;
       const char *filepath = "/tmp/sharedfile";

       if ((fd = open(filepath, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, (mode_t)00700)) == -1) {
           perror("open");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       data = mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
       if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
           perror("mmap");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }


       for (index= 0; index < 200; index++) {
           data[index] = 'G';
       } 

       sleep(10);

       // We must see 'Goose' at the beginning of memory-mapped file.
       for (index= 0; index < 200; index++) {
           fprintf(stdout, "%c", data[index]);
       }

       for (index= 0; index < 200; index++) {
           data[index] = 'H';
       }

       if (msync(data, 12288, MS_SYNC) == -1) {
           perror("Error sync to disk");
       } 

       if (munmap(data, 12288) == -1) {
           close(fd);
           perror("Error un-mmapping");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       close(fd);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the example - do you happen to know if Mono's MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile will work with an object created with shm_open instead of open? I expect that it will, but haven't found any documentation - I'll try it out myself when I get a chance to get back to this part of the project.

I'm interested in using shm_open because I really don't need this to hit the disk, and the buffer will be constantly updated whenever the system is on, so it will be constantly writing to the disk if it is file-backed.

Comment: Just a hint: A bytes cannot be -1. It can contain values from 0..255. If it's a signed byte then it can hold -128 to +128.

So this:

var data = stream.ReadByte ();
                    while (data != -1)

Wont work

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden you get -1 value when reaching the end of stream.

Comment: I noticed that the variable is defined as "var", which is essentially the same as a variant. It will adapt in order for the value you assign to fit. If it was a fixed byte field -1 would not fit and you would get an out of range exception.

E.g:

UByte value = stream.readByte(1);

Here a value of -1 would only be valid if "value" was a signed byte, otherwise only values between 0 to 255 are valid.

But since it's an untyped var, any value can be stored in it.

Comment: @Jon: var isn't untyped and stream.ReadByte() doesn't return bytes, but ints, which is why -1 is a valid result.

Comment: When you create a variable With the "var" keyword, it will adopt the datatype of whatever first element you assign to it.